How can I prove this stronger version of Fedder's Criterion?
I was reading Fedder's original paper which proved what is now known as "Fedder's criterion". I noticed that the abstract stated something which is a priori stronger than what is proved in the paper. The abstract states

"It is proven that when $R=S/I$ is the quotient of a [characteristic $p$] regular local ring $S$, $R$ is
$F$-pure at the prime ideal $Q$ if and only if $(I^{[p]}: I)\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}$."

On the other hand, Theorem 1.12 states

"Let $(S,m)$ be a regular local ring of characteristic $p$ and let
$R=S/I$. Then $R$ is $F$-pure if and only if $(I^{[p]}: I)\nsubseteq m^{[p]}$."

As far as I can tell, the version stated in the abstract is never proved explicitly. So, I was wondering how to get from the version on the theorem in Theorem 1.12 to the version stated in the abstract. One direction is straightforward: Suppose $R$ is $F$-pure at $Q$, meaning $R_{Q}$ is $F$-pure. Since $R_{Q}\cong S_Q/IS_Q$, Theorem 1.12 implies $((IS_Q)^{[p]} :_{S_Q} IS_Q)\nsubseteq (QS_Q)^{[p]}$. But of course $(QS_Q)^{[p]}=Q^{[p]}S_Q$ and $((IS_Q)^{[p]}:_{S_Q}IS_Q)$ $=(I^{[p]}S_Q:_{S_Q}IS_Q)$ $=(I^{[p]}:I)S_Q$, so we have $(I^{[p]}:I)S_Q\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}S_Q$ which implies $(I^{[p]}:I)\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}$.
For the converse, I hit a snag. Given that $(I^{[p]}:I)\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}$, I want to say that $(I^{[p]}:I)S_Q\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}S_Q$, and from there, Theorem 1.12 will give us that $R$ is $F$-pure at $Q$. However, it is not clear to me why $(I^{[p]}:I)\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}$ should imply $(I^{[p]}:I)S_Q\nsubseteq Q^{[p]}S_Q$. Note that this implication is equivalent to saying that if $\frac{(I^{[p]}:I)+Q^{[p]}}{Q^{[p]}}\neq 0$, then $Q$ is in its support.
One method to show this might be to show that $Q$ is an associated prime of $\frac{(I^{[p]}:I)+Q^{[p]}}{Q^{[p]}}$. Since $0\neq\frac{(I^{[p]}:I)+Q^{[p]}}{Q^{[p]}}\subseteq S/Q^{[n]}$, the associated primes of $\frac{(I^{[p]}:I)+Q^{[p]}}{Q^{[p]}}$ are a nonempty subset of $\operatorname{Ass}_S(S/Q^{[p]})$. Thus, if $Q$ is the only associated prime of $S/Q^{[p]}$, then we are done. But it seems plausible to me that $S/Q^{[p]}$ could have other associated primes (though, I don't have an example). Anyone have ideas?
